# How to inject Blazor-WebAssembly-app extension-UI in webpage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-chrome-extension, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to build a chrome-extension with "Blazor-webassembly-app". It works fine when it is on browser action button. The thing is when it is on browser action it loads index.html file and in that file there is a tag `<app>Loading for calling the APP.razor content...</app>` So when index.html file runs it calls app-tag which then calls app.razor page's content then app.razor page calls mainLayout.razor page's contents and other razor pages' contents. This is all working perfectly while handling through browser action button. The pictures I have attached below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v5Rn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgOpN.png)

**Now what I'm trying to is** injecting that whole extension UI into my webpage for example in google webpage.

***This is my manifest.json code:***

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "WebAssembly C#",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": ".NET inside a chrome extension",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      // "js/background.js",
      "js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
      "js/site.js"
      //"framework/wasm/dotnet.3.2.0",
      //"framework/wasm/dotnet.timezones.dat",
      //"framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm"
      //"framework/blazor.webassembly.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": [
        "css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
        "css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css",
        "css/app.css",
        "css/StyleSheet.css"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.ae/*",
        "https://www.google.am/*",
        "https://www.google.as/*",
        "https://www.google.at/*",
        "https://www.google.az/*",
        "https://www.google.ba/*",
        "https://www.google.be/*",
        "https://www.google.bg/*",
        "https://www.google.bi/*",
        "https://www.google.bs/*",
        "https://www.google.ca/*",
        "https://www.google.cd/*",
        "https://www.google.cg/*",
        "https://www.google.ch/*",
        "https://www.google.ci/*",
        "https://www.google.cl/*",
        "https://www.google.co.bw/*",
        "https://www.google.co.ck/*",
        "https://www.google.co.cr/*",
        "https://www.google.co.hu/*",
        "https://www.google.co.id/*",
        "https://www.google.co.il/*",
        "https://www.google.co.im/*",
        "https://www.google.co.in/*",
        "https://www.google.co.je/*",
        "https://www.google.co.jp/*",
        "https://www.google.co.ke/*",
        "https://www.google.co.kr/*",
        "https://www.google.co.ls/*",
        "https://www.google.co.ma/*",
        "https://www.google.co.nz/*",
        "https://www.google.co.th/*",
        "https://www.google.co.ug/*",
        "https://www.google.co.uk/*",
        "https://www.google.co.uz/*",
        "https://www.google.co.ve/*",
        "https://www.google.co.vi/*",
        "https://www.google.co.za/*",
        "https://www.google.co.zm/*",
        "https://www.google.com.af/*",
        "https://www.google.com.ag/*",
        "https://www.google.com.ar/*",
        "https://www.google.com.au/*",
        "https://www.google.com.bd/*",
        "https://www.google.com.bo/*",
        "https://www.google.com.br/*",
        "https://www.google.com.bz/*",
        "https://www.google.com.co/*",
        "https://www.google.com.cu/*",
        "https://www.google.com.do/*",
        "https://www.google.com.ec/*",
        "https://www.google.com.eg/*",
        "https://www.google.com.et/*",
        "https://www.google.com.fj/*",
        "https://www.google.com.gi/*",
        "https://www.google.com.gt/*",
        "https://www.google.com.hk/*",
        "https://www.google.com.jm/*",
        "https://www.google.com.kw/*",
        "https://www.google.com.ly/*",
        "https://www.google.com.mt/*",
        "https://www.google.com.mx/*",
        "https://www.google.com.my/*",
        "https://www.google.com.na/*",
        "https://www.google.com.nf/*",
        "https://www.google.com.ni/*",
        "https://www.google.com.np/*",
        "https://www.google.com.om/*",
        "https://www.google.com.pa/*",
        "https://www.google.com.pe/*",
        "https://www.google.com.ph/*",
        "https://www.google.com.pk/*",
        "https://www.google.com.pr/*",
        "https://www.google.com.py/*",
        "https://www.google.com.qa/*",
        "https://www.google.com.sa/*",
        "https://www.google.com.sb/*",
        "https://www.google.com.sg/*",
        "https://www.google.com.sv/*",
        "https://www.google.com.tj/*",
        "https://www.google.com.tr/*",
        "https://www.google.com.tw/*",
        "https://www.google.com.ua/*",
        "https://www.google.com.uy/*",
        "https://www.google.com.uz/*",
        "https://www.google.com.vc/*",
        "https://www.google.com.vn/*",
        "https://www.google.com/*",
        "https://www.google.cz/*",
        "https://www.google.de/*",
        "https://www.google.dj/*",
        "https://www.google.dk/*",
        "https://www.google.dm/*",
        "https://www.google.ee/*",
        "https://www.google.es/*",
        "https://www.google.fi/*",
        "https://www.google.fm/*",
        "https://www.google.fr/*",
        "https://www.google.gg/*",
        "https://www.google.gl/*",
        "https://www.google.gm/*",
        "https://www.google.gr/*",
        "https://www.google.hn/*",
        "https://www.google.hr/*",
        "https://www.google.ht/*",
        "https://www.google.hu/*",
        "https://www.google.ie/*",
        "https://www.google.is/*",
        "https://www.google.it/*",
        "https://www.google.jo/*",
        "https://www.google.kg/*",
        "https://www.google.kz/*",
        "https://www.google.li/*",
        "https://www.google.lk/*",
        "https://www.google.lt/*",
        "https://www.google.lu/*",
        "https://www.google.lv/*",
        "https://www.google.md/*",
        "https://www.google.mn/*",
        "https://www.google.ms/*",
        "https://www.google.mu/*",
        "https://www.google.mw/*",
        "https://www.google.net/*",
        "https://www.google.nl/*",
        "https://www.google.no/*",
        "https://www.google.nr/*",
        "https://www.google.nu/*",
        "https://www.google.off.ai/*",
        "https://www.google.org/*",
        "https://www.google.pl/*",
        "https://www.google.pn/*",
        "https://www.google.pt/*",
        "https://www.google.ro/*",
        "https://www.google.ru/*",
        "https://www.google.rw/*",
        "https://www.google.sc/*",
        "https://www.google.se/*",
        "https://www.google.sh/*",
        "https://www.google.si/*",
        "https://www.google.sk/*",
        "https://www.google.sm/*",
        "https://www.google.sn/*",
        "https://www.google.tm/*",
        "https://www.google.to/*",
        "https://www.google.tp/*",
        "https://www.google.tt/*",
        "https://www.google.tv/*",
        "https://www.google.uz/*",
        "https://www.google.vg/*",
        "https://www.google.vu/*",
        "https://www.google.ws/*"
        //"https://www.facebook.com/"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": [
        "js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
        "js/init.js",
        "js/site.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "icons": { "128": "webassembly.png" },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "index.html",
    "js/init.js",
    "js/site.js",
    "framework/wasm/dotnet.3.2.0",
    "framework/wasm/dotnet.timezones.dat",
    "framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm",
    "css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.svg",
    "css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.ttf"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-v8v3RKRPmN4odZ1CWM5gw80QKPCCWMcpNeOmimNL2AA='; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I load my background_scripts file "Init.js" in this file code

```
(function () {
    //alert("Hello from Init.js i.e; content_script").
    $.get(chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html'), function (data) {
        debugger
        $(data).appendTo('#rhs').
    }).
})().
```

I'm getting a content of index.html file. you can see it in picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNadc.png)

and this is code and content of index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>WebAssemblyBlazorChromeExtension</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading for calling the APP.razor content...</app>
    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="js/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

which then have the **app-tag** which will call the **app.razor** page's content. you can see it in app.razor file code:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <p>You found the routeData.</p>
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

but instead of calling app.razor page content application do nothing it stops after displaying **index.html page's content** .
I don't even know if app.razor page found the route or notFound the route.Bboth found and notFound contents are not displaying anything.
I'm attaching my errors screen shots here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9RcK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pmCa.png)

I hope, I explained my problem clearly and sorry if I use bad grammar. I'm happy to share my extension file you can then run it on your browser to check what am I doing wrong .
I'm actually new to Blazor-extension extension.

Comment: The best method is to create an `iframe` element and point it to an html file inside your extension. The html file should be listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). Inside that iframe you will have a full extension environment just like inside browserAction. There are many examples, look for one yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you please refer me one r two example links.

Answer (score 3):

Running a Blazor WebAssembly in the content scripts is a little bit more tricky.

A Chrome extension only allows loading JavaScript files as part of the content scripts. So you have to import the Blazor and DotNet JavaScript files and call to `Blazor.start` in your content script. However, the shipped Blazor and DotNet JS files does not support importing with ES6 `import()`.

To make building Blazor WebAssembly to browser extension easier, I have created a package in the repository [Blazor.BrowserExtension](https://github.com/mingyaulee/Blazor.BrowserExtension). You can follow the steps in the link to convert your existing project. After that, follow the [extra steps](https://github.com/mingyaulee/Blazor.BrowserExtension#add-a-content-script) to add a content script to your extension.

> Extras:
>
> Chrome Extensions APIs are accessible in Razor pages or from dependency injection. The APIs are imported from another package [WebExtension.Net](https://github.com/mingyaulee/WebExtension.Net).

Another option is to download the package [Blazor.BrowserExtension.Build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazor.BrowserExtension.Build/) which contains the build targets needed to build your Blazor project into a browser extension.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static class IJSRuntimeExtensionMethods
{
    public static async ValueTask InitializeInactivityTimer<T>(this IJSRuntime js,
          DotNetObjectReference<T> dotNetObjectReference) where T : class
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeInactivityTimer", dotNetObjectReference);
    }
    public static ValueTask<object> SetInLocalStorage(this IJSRuntime js, string key, string content)
     => js.InvokeAsync<object>("localStorage.setItem", key, content);
    public static ValueTask<string> GetFromLocalStorage(this IJSRuntime js, string key)
        => js.InvokeAsync<string>( "localStorage.getItem", key);
    public static ValueTask<object> RemoveItem(this IJSRuntime js, string key)
        => js.InvokeAsync<object>("localStorage.removeItem", key);
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. The purpose of SO is to help as many people as possible with the answers given here. And though the code may be clear to you and tell the whole story, this is unlikely true for many users here. If you can find the time, we would appreciate it. An explanation will also improve your chances to get upvotes.